# ember/npm addon with dependencies/ devDependencies

Tags: node.js, ember.js, npm, npm-install

I have created an ember addon which relies on gulp derived packages to build, so in the addon it has the following in package.json.

When the addon is included in the main application, the build fails due to the various gulp modules being missing. The addon is in the devDependencies section of the main application.

The addon also builds into the main application when it is in through `npm link`. My question is how should the addon dependencies be handled so the main application builds without a local copy of the module?

**Update:** I think the problem is that the package does a gulp build after the postinstall which elevates the gulp devDependencies into real dependencies. Is this correct?

Addon JSON file

```json
{
  "name": "My Addon",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "The default blueprint for ember-cli addons.",
  "directories": {
    "doc": "doc",
    "test": "tests"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "ember build",
    "start": "ember server",
    "test": "ember try:each",
    "postinstall": "gulp build && bower install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git://github.com/myaddon.git"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 0.12.0"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "broccoli-asset-rev": "^2.4.5",
    "broccoli-funnel": "^1.0.9",
    "ember-ajax": "^2.4.1",
    // more ember modules
    "find-root": "^0.1.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "glob": "^4.5.3",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-clean-css": "^2.2.1",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-connect": "^2.2.0",
    "gulp-filter": "^3.0.1",
    "gulp-git": "^1.4.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.3.2",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^1.5.2",
    "gulp-task-loader": "^1.2.1",
    "gulp-template": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "^1.2.0",
    "gulp-zip": "^3.0.2",
    "lazypipe": "^1.0.1",
    "loader.js": "^4.0.10",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "ember-addon"
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "ember-cli-babel": "^5.1.7"
  },
  "ember-addon": {
    "configPath": "tests/dummy/config"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The addon's dependencies are needed to build application (that includes addon), should be listed in `dependencies` section. The `devDependencies` of a package that is included as dependency of another package, are ignored.

There is other solution to [add packages](https://ember-cli.com/api/classes/Blueprint.html#method_addPackageToProject) into an application. You can create a [blueprint](https://ember-cli.com/extending/#default-blueprint) in your addon that will be called every time an application build with it or install it.